# MS Word inappropriate tooltip repeatedly appears

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I find in MS Word 2010 that when I have a chart in my document, whenever I leave the cursor still, a tooltip appears telling me that I am hovering over the chart area (see image below).  Is there any way to fix this?  (I am running Win 7 SP1 if that helps at all)

[image: Example of inappropriate tooltip]

Comment: Does this occur only when the mouse is near the chart, or only on the same page, or any page in the document? How big is the chart?

Comment: @Adam - there are two charts in the document, each taking up a whole page.  This tooltip pops up irrespective of where I am in the document though, and I've found it occurs in more than just this one document,but whenever I have any chart in a document.

Comment: I noticed that you're document is in tracked changes mode.  What happens when you view it without the markup?

Comment: @Karen927 - I've disabled track changes (and removed comments FWIW), but this issue still occurs.

Comment: Try disabling the screen tip feature in Word.  To do that, go to Word Options, select the "Popular" tab and change the settings for "Screentip style".

Comment: @Karen927 - +1 for your efforts, but for some reason, although I've disabled the 'Screentips' completely, the tooltip still appears.

Comment: Happens to me too across multiple versions & computers. Seems that Microsoft re-used code but never fixed this bug. Microsoft re-using code isn't something new- Windows 10 is still based on Windows NT, for example.